# TunnelBroker/Hurricane Electric Forums

Tags: ipv6, tunnel

Apologies if this is an inappropriate question to ask on SU. It just seems to be my only option.

I set up an IPv6 tunnel with HE.net about a year ago, and their tech support has been reasonably helpful, but I seem to have no way to create an account to access their forums.

https://forums.he.net/index.php

I would normally say, "Very Helpful" because when I have asked their tech support questions, I get answers..except for this one. When it comes to forum access, I get utterly ignored. No replies, or replies only to other the questions I've asked in the email.

I've even passed their IPV6 Sage certification and got the t-shirt. Nope, that wasn't it.

At some point, I even figured out what the url would be to get to the account creation page and got an error about it not being available.

People seem to be creating accounts and posting there.

Any idea what's up with the cone of silence?

Comment: You already have an account! Just log in.

Comment: When I do that I get "Password security has recently been upgraded. Please enter your password again.". I do that and I get "incorrect password"

Comment: I reset the password and now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember creating an account there. But I've just gone to [forum login page](https://forums.he.net/index.php?action=login) and used my tunnelbroker account and it works.

Comment: Done that too. I get "Password security has recently been upgraded. Please enter your password again.". I do that and I get "incorrect password", but I'm still able to log in everywhere else on the site.

Comment: I did a password reset and now it works